# Prettify symbols without screwing up alignment

Tags: align, prettify-symbols-mode

Is there a way to prettify symbols without running into alignment issues? E.g. replacing `not` with `¬`is visually pleasing, but screws up code alignment, b/c `not` is 3 chars while `¬` is one char.

Since prettifying symbols only changes the way text is displayed, not how it's actually stored, it doesn't make sense for operations like text alignment to use the prettified instead of underlying representations.

Comment: Agreed; I consider the feature unusable on account of this issue.

Comment: http://endlessparentheses.com/using-prettify-symbols-in-clojure-and-elisp-without-breaking-indentation.html is about padding the 'pretty' symbol so that it's *actually* the same width as the text it's replacing, which works around the alignment issue (at the cost of not being quite as pretty). I can see that being acceptable for very short text, but not for something like the word "lambda", so YMMV.

Comment: `lambda` is OK b/c you don't align with the end of the word, but with the second character, so it works out. That's not the case with `not`, etc.

Comment: Good point; it would be an abnormal formatting of a lambda form for it to trigger an issue (e.g. a "one liner" where the body actually ended up being split over a second line). Not a typical scenario at all.

Comment: `(push '("not" . (?\s (Bc . Bl) ?¬ (Br . Bc) ?\s (Bl . Br) ?\s)) prettify-symbols-alist)` is one way to make `not` align. You can fiddle around with the spaces etc. as in http://endlessparentheses.com/using-prettify-symbols-in-clojure-and-elisp-without-breaking-indentation.html to make it the way you want it. Although, I'd consider it a much nicer solution to have a wider symbol, but I don't think you can do that within prettify-symbols, you'll probably have to mess with `set-fontset-font` for that.